# How to increase login session expiry time in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony2 Security for an admin panel. The session expiry time is very low; every time I have to login to access the admin section. So how do I implement the remember me feature so that once an admin logs in, he is logged in forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [*Remember Me*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html) cookbook entry. Set `lifetime` to something big and force the `remember me`:

```
remember_me:
    lifetime: 31536000 # a year
    always_remember_me: true
```